# Code Generator doGenerate does not generate code to txt-file in Example Xtext Project

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I am trying to understand how code generator doGenerate invokes. I took an example Xtext Project without any custom changes (only Greetings). By Default code generator looks like this:

```
override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
    fsa.generateFile('greetings.txt', 'People to greet: ' + 
        resource.allContents
            .filter(Greeting)
            .map[name]
            .join(', '))
}
```

After I ran the Generated Eclipse Plug-in and created new Java Project with file in /src with right extention (src.MyDsl). and converted project to xtext nature, I wrote some greetings and saved. But in src-gen I did not see generated file greetings.txt.
So Interpreter works but does not save code.

I have found in [Question: xtext-dogenerate method is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625211/xtext-dogenerate-method-is-not-called) that the file, where I want to save code, needs the right file extension (case sensitive) --(done), the project - xtext nature --(done) and build automatically needs to be enabled.

My Question is how can I enable it to use doGenerate Code Generator automatically? So I could see generated code in greetings.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make sure

- your model project has Xtext nature and builder (right-click, configure) - you should be asked if you open the file
- you have build automatically enabled
- if the model project is a java project model files should be in a source folder
- the file extension is correct (case sensitive) `src.MyDsl` looks suspicious in that regards

Comment: OOOPs!  thank u so much, with src.mydsl it works.  I have got it. I have done a mistake in extention... just  no words :)